# what does _? mean in the following regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

What does `_?` mean in the following rails regex?

```
/\A_?[a-z]_?(?:[a-z0-9.-]_?)*\z/i
```

I have attempted to decipher the regex as follows

```
# regex explained
# \A    :    matches the beginning of the string
# _?    :    
# [     :    beginning of character group
# a-z   :    any lowercase letter
# ]     :    end of character group
# _?    :    
# (     :    is a capture group, anything matched within the parens is saved for later use
# ?:    :    non-capturing group: matches below, but doesn't store a back-ref
# [     :    beginning of character group
# a-z   :    any lowercase letter
# A-Z   :    any uppercase letter
# 0-9   :    any digit
# .     :    a fullstop or "any character" ??????
# _     :    an underscore
# ]     :    end of character group
# _?    :    
# )     :    See above
# *     :    zero or more times of the given characters
# \z    :    is the end of the string
```

Comment: `_` has no special meaning, it's just an underscore. `_?` is an optional underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` means that the previous expression should appear 0 or 1 times, similarly to how `*` means it should match 0 or more times, or `+` means it should match 1 or more times.

So, for example, with the RE `/\A_?[A-Z]?\z/`, the following strings will match:

- `_O`
- `_`
- `P`

but these will not:

- `____`
- `A_`
- `PP`

The RE you posted originally states:

1. The string may begin with an underscore
2. Then there must be a lowercase letter
3. Then there may be another underscore
4. For the rest of the string, there must be a letter, number, period, or -, which may be followed by an underscore

Example strings that match this RE:

- `_a_abcdefg`
- `b_abc_def_`
- `_qasdf_poiu_`
- `a12345_`
- `z._.._...._......_`
- `u`

Answer (score 2):

`_` matches an underscore.

`?` matches zero or one of the preceeding character; basically making the preceeding character optional.

So `_?` will match one underscore if it is present, and will match without it.

Answer (score 1):

`_?` means `_` is optional.

It can accept `_sadasd_sadsadsa_asdasdasd_` or `asdasdsadasdasd` i.e `_` separated strings where `_` is optional.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/89